# how to make SQL statements in same value

Tags: sql, oracle

Table:

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| QW | 1 | 42 |
| QW | 2 |  |
| QW | 3 | 12 |
| EW | 3 |  |
| EW | 2 |  |
| R | 1 | 52 |
| T | 2 |  |
| Y | 3 |  |
| UY | 1 | 1 |
| IO | 2 |  |
| PO | 3 |  |
| PP | 4 | 1 |
| IU | 12 |  |
| PP | 5 | 55 |

expected output：

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| QW1 |  | 42 |
| QW2 |  |  |
| QW3 |  | 12 |
| EW3 |  |  |
| EW2 |  |  |
| R | 1 | 52 |
| T | 2 |  |
| Y | 3 |  |
| UY | 1 | 1 |
| IO | 2 |  |
| PO | 3 |  |
| PP4 |  | 1 |
| IU | 12 |  |
| PP5 |  | 55 |

In the table **`col[A]`** have repeating some same values throughout the rows. For those rows, need to make them concatenated with **`col[B]`** such as **`col[A]+col[B]`** as column **`A`**, and undisplay column **`B`**

But I don't know how to make the SQL statements.Please help~

Comment: Please write the tables in text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use conditional logic along with `COUNT() OVER ()` analytic function such as

```sql
SELECT A||CASE WHEN COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY A)>1 THEN B END AS a,
       CASE WHEN COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY A)=1 THEN B END AS b,
       c
  FROM t
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=55c158e8ae0dba3ae272c06fdf2e07c5)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

You can use `window` function `row_number` which assign sequential integer to each row and apply `partition by` clause to get smaller sets or partitions. In your case you have to partition by column A and concat column `A` and `B` if your `row_number`(here in this case count)  greater than `1`. Then you will get your expected result.

```
select  case when count > 1 then A || B else A end as A,
 B, C from (
        select A, B, C, ROW_NUMBER () OVER  ( PARTITION BY A) as count 
from your_table_name
 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one option:

Sample data:

```
SQL> with test (a, b) as
  2    (select 'QW', 1 from dual union all
  3     select 'QW', 2 from dual union all
  4     select 'QW', 3 from dual union all
  5     select 'EW', 3 from dual union all
  6     select 'EW', 2 from dual union all
  7     select 'R' , 1 from dual union all
  8     select 'T' , 2 from dual union all
  9     select 'Y' , 3 from dual union all
 10     select 'UY', 1 from dual union all
 11     select 'IO', 2 from dual union all
 12     select 'PO', 3 from dual union all
 13     select 'PP', 4 from dual union all
 14     select 'IU',12 from dual union all
 15     select 'PP', 5 from dual
 16    ),
```

Count number of appearances of each `a` column value

```
 17  counts as
 18    (select a, count(*) cnt
 19     from test
 20     group by a
 21    )
```

Join with `CASE` expression

```
 22  select t.a || case when c.cnt > 1 then t.b end as a,
 23         case when c.cnt > 1 then null else t.b end as b
 24  from test t join counts c on t.a = c.a;

A              B
---------- -----
QW1
QW2
QW3
EW3
EW2
R              1
T              2
Y              3
UY             1
IO             2
PO             3
PP4
IU            12
PP5

14 rows selected.

SQL>
```